# In the windows system（win11 or win10）, git cannot be used normally, especially in the process of using IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Regardless of whether it is the low version or the high version of Git, it is always unable to clone, pull, and push in IDEA, but it occasionally works but always fails. After a certain period of normality, it starts to fail frequently. Clicking Test Git several times will result in an error prompt, but I can execute git operations in the command line terminal. I start IDEA as an administrator, but still cannot solve this problem. I uninstall and reinstall Git, but it does not work. Even after reinstalling Windows and reinstalling Git and IDEA, it still does not work.

Couldn't check commit: git4idea.config.GitVersionIdentificationException: Cannot identify version of git executable C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
[image]
Other information, when using gitbash(administrator identity) : will appear
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like idea is trying to find git at `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`.
Have you made sure that git is installed at that location?

You may also try changing where idea is looking for git. This is probably in the settings for the git4idea plugin.

Comment: Yes, git, of course, under this path. Most of the time, it can be detected in the IDEA settings panel, but it will occasionally fail, but using git in IDEA is ineffective, but occasionally can operate normally, it can be operated normally.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean